# "mini-" vs "mini (space)" vs "mini (no space)?

Tags: prefixes

I think words like miniskirt are usually written together.

But what about other words like mini-fridge? Or even most uncommon words like mini can?

I usually see the three type of usages on Google.

So, how to tell which one to use? Or they are all okay?

Comment: Apart from dictionaries, you can use Google Books and Google Books Ngram Viewer to see whether there are any hits for your preferred spelling (in books written by native speakers of English, that is); if there are, you can use that spelling. There are no hard-and-fast rules, as you've noticed.

Comment: As @userr2684291 states, "There are no hard-and-fast rules, " Furthermore, rules are evolving, usually in the direction of removing punctuation. E.G. `chick-pea` has long-ago been changed to `chickpea` (or is that `long ago`?) See https://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-hyphen-1/thousands-of-hyphens-perish-as-english-marches-on-idUSHAR15384620070921